# Semantic meaning of "There's no line here to end."

Tags: compilation-error, line

I often have the experience that LaTeX returns an error message "There's no line here to end.". Then, it gives the location of the error, showing a full line of text:

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 \noindent
               Full line of text \\
?
```

Apparently, the message was referring to something other than the line which is being shown to the user. However, I can never remember what is the actual meaning of the message. Is there a good mnemonic for remembering what the words "line", "here" and "end" mean to LaTeX in this context, so that I don't get confused next time?

In this case the previous line was `\hrule \\`, and the error went away when I changed it to `\hrule \ \\`, but I don't see how to get that from the error message.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\hrule \\
\noindent Full line of text \\
\end{document}
```

I am using a package called "texlive". I'm also not sure what is the difference between `\hrule \ \\` and `\hrule \quad \\`, or why the original was less correct and merited the error message. I guess there are a lot of questions about documents that result in this message when compiled, but I'm interested in the message itself and how to understand it as a natural language sentence.

Comment: using `\ \\ ` is worse than just using `\\ ` as it avoids the error _message_ while still producing bad output. Better to remove the offending `\\ `

Answer (score 5):

You should almost never use `\\`  outside of tables or math alignmments. If used in text it forces a linebreak, leaving the line short.

In

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\hrule \\
\noindent Full line of text \\
\end{document}
```

the error is the `\\`   after `\hrule` as `\hrule` does not start horizontal mode, so there is no line to end so the `\\`  gives an error. As `\\`  looks ahead in case there is a `[5pt]` optional argument, tex has started reading the next line, which is why it is shown on the line after the `\\` .

That is: The meaning of `\\`  is "end line" but if you use it at the  start of a paragraph before the first line of text then there is, as the message says, "no line to end".

The `\noindent` is doing nothing after an `\\`  as that prevents indent at the start of a paragraph but `\\`  is not a paragraph break.

Just remove both `\\`  from this document. The first is an error and the second doesn't generate an error but the underfull warning of badness 10000, and produces bad output.

So the correct markup should have no `\\`  or `\noindent`, possibly

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
\hrule 
Full line of text
\end{document}
```

Comment: The key part of your answer seems to be the `\usepackage{parskip}`, which you don't explain at all. The part that you do explain, doesn't answer the question: what do the words mean? I'm trying to pretend that English is my second language. For example, you could say, "'line ... here ... end' means to me that I should look at the previous line in the document, and Google to learn what a *horizontal mode* is, and then try to figure out if that has something to do with the problem".

Comment: @Metamorphic sorry you didn't find the answer as helpful as I'd hoped. the bit about `parskip` isn't the main part at all that was just a final comment to say what to do rather than answer the question asked. If you had asked how to separate paragraphs by space that would have been the answer (except the question would have been closed as duplicate) but you asked what the words mean, and I though I went through the error message word by word. The main part of the answer is the paragraph starting `That is:` which I hoped explained every word in the message.